# How do i store a byte array in Arduino flash memory using PROGMEM?

Tags: c, arrays, flash, arduino, byte

Hello everyone i am new to the world of Arduino and i am having problems storing temporary values in Arduino RAM so i thought i would store them in flash storage using PROGMEM.
 i am trying to store 2 byte arrays but i cant get them to display after they are stored. After some testing i cant get Serial Print to work properly either but if in the mean time somebody can better explain PROGMEM that would be helpful. my code so far is:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
struct GRID{
  boolean isOn;
  uint16_t color;
  uint8_t X;
  uint8_t Y;
};

GRID landed[10][22];
GRID falling[22][10];

//PROGMEM prog_uint8_t xAxis[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
//PROGMEM prog_uint8_t yAxis[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22};

uint8_t xAxis[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
uint8_t yAxis[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22};

void iniLanded(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 22; j++){
      landed[i][j].color=0x0000;
      landed[i][j].X = xAxis[i];
      landed[i][j].Y = yAxis[j];
    }
}

void iniFalling(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      falling[i][j].color=0x0000;
      falling[i][j].X = xAxis[j];
      falling[i][j].Y = yAxis[i];
    }
}

void printLanded(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 22; j++){
      Serial.print(landed[i][j].X); Serial.print(" "); Serial.println(landed[i][j].Y);
    }
}

void printFalling(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      Serial.print(landed[i][j].X); Serial.print(" "); Serial.println(landed[i][j].Y);
    }
}

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  iniLanded();
  iniFalling();

}

void loop(){
  Serial.println(F("Hello World!"));
  delay(100);
  /*printLanded();
  delay(100);
  printFalling();
  delay(100);*/
}
```

Comment: to those who are wondering why nothing is printing in serial it's because the Arduino runs out of RAM during the second initialize function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is in the way you call from flash. See my example [this is where I define](http://mpflaga.github.io/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/_s_f_e_m_p3_shield_8cpp_source.html#l00025) much like your commented code.
and here is where you call back the data. Note the use of pgm_read_word_near and the deference &. Where there are other similar functions [found here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html) for byte, word, etc...

Comment: i changed uint8_t xAxis to unsigned char xAxis[10] PROGMEM = {...}; and when i need to use it i use pgm_read_byte(&(xAxis[i])); is there a differnce between pgm_read_byte and pgm_read_word ?

Comment: pgm_read_word will read two bytes. Note you are using an array. Hence the pgm function needs to know or line up the size of the elements in the array.

Comment: ok i wouldn't need to use integers greater than 256 so i think read_byte is ok for me. on a separate note how does prog_void work?